# Can we use multiple db instances in hibernate at a time?

Tags: java, hibernate

My requirement is, I have two db instances in db2 with same db schema. We take backup of db every year. So we have db like dbinstance_2014, dbinstance_2015 and dbinstance_2016. 
My application is working on 2016 instance. I need to create report year wise in that case I need to use older instances. I have create two methods to create session factory. One method will create current years dbinstance connection and other will dynamically create connection to older db.
Current year `sessionFactory` is used throughout the application. In case of report generation I am trying to use another method which creates sessionfactory dynamically.

But I am getting exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Basically Hibernate supports to have multiple schema at with two different session factory. Not sure how do yo use it ?

Comment: It is possible by the use of multiple session factories, for the usage purpose you inject session from a particular factory to a particular class where access of that particular DB is required, here is a link : http://www.javabeat.net/configuring-multiple-databases-in-hibernate/ try it